# Entire function missing 2 values

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f$ is entire of finite order, and doesn't assume $2$ values in the complex plane.

Is there a way to prove that $f$ is costant without using Picard theorem ?

Comment: Kind of. If $f$ misses two values, these are without loss of generality $0$ and $1$. $\lambda \colon \mathbb{H}\to \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0,1\}$ is a universal covering, so, since $\mathbb{C}$ is simply connected, $f$ lifts to an entire $F \colon \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{H}$, but that must be constant by Liouville ($\mathbb{H} \cong \mathbb{D}$). But that proves Picard, so it's sort of cheating.

Comment: @DanielFischer: what is $\lambda$ ?

Comment: [The modular function $\lambda$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lambda_function). But that was a tongue-in-cheek suggestion, the serious answer is below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, for functions of finite order, we can prove it in an elementary way. If $f$ has finite order, so has $f - c$ for any $c \in \mathbb{C}$, so we may assume that $f$ misses $0$. Then, as a function of finite order without zeros,

$$f(z) = e^{P(z)}$$

for a polynomial $P$. If $f$ is not constant, $P$ is not constant, and as a polynomial, it follows that $P$ attains every complex value. But then $f$ attains every complex value except $0$, so misses only one value.